# why the chart is not showing up?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I've working on code for R visualization task on Rstudio. At first all seem fine until I realize the chart is not feasible on dashboard in web browser. here's the code :

````
```
# UI starter code
url <- "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DV0151EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module_4/starter_code/ui.R"
download.file(url, destfile = "ui.R")
```
# Server starter code
url <- "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DV0151EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module_4/starter_code/server.R"
download.file(url, destfile = "server.R")
```
# Dataset
url <- "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DV0151EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module_4/starter_code/adult.csv"
download.file(url, destfile = "adult.csv")
```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
```
# UI code
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Trends in Demographics and Income"),
```
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 12,
               wellPanel(
                   selectInput("country", "Native Country", choices = c("United-States", "Canada", "Mexico", "Germany", "Philippines"))
               )
        )
    ),
```
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 3,
               wellPanel(
                   radioButtons("continuous_variable", "Continuous Variable:", choices = c("AGE", "HOURS_PER_WEEK")),
                   radioButtons("graph_type", "Graph Type:", choices = c("Histogram", "Boxplot"))
               )
        ),
```
        column(width = 9,
               plotOutput("p1")
        )
    ),
```
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 3,
               wellPanel(
                   radioButtons("categorical_variable", "Categorical Variable:", choices = c("EDUCATION","WORKCLASS","SEX")),
                   checkboxInput("is_stacked", "Stacked")
               )
        ),
```
        column(width = 9,
               plotOutput("p2")
        )
    )
)
```
# Server code
server <- function(input, output) {

    adult <- read.csv("adult.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    df_country <- reactive({
        df_country <- adult %>%
            filter(NATIVE_COUNTRY == input$country)
        print(str(df_country)) # add print statement to check df_country
        return(df_country)
    })
```
    output$p1 <- renderPlot({
        print(input$continuous_variable) # add print statement to check input value
        print(input$graph_type) # add print statement to check input value
        ggplot(df_country(), aes_string(x = input$continuous_variable, fill = "PREDICTION")) +
            facet_grid(. ~ "PREDICTION") +
            {if(input$graph_type == "Histogram") geom_histogram() else geom_boxplot()}
    })
```
    output$p2 <- renderPlot({
        print(input$categorical_variable) # add print statement to check input value
        print(input$is_stacked) # add print statement to check input value
        if(input$is_stacked) {
            ggplot(df_country(), aes_string(x = input$categorical_variable, fill = "PREDICTION")) +
                facet_grid(. ~ "PREDICTION") +
                geom_bar(position = "stack", color = "black", alpha = 0.7, width = 0.5)
        } else {
            ggplot(df_country(), aes_string(x = input$categorical_variable, fill = "PREDICTION")) +
                facet_grid(. ~ "PREDICTION") +
                geom_bar(color = "black", alpha = 0.7, width = 0.5)
        }
    })
}
```
# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```
````

please help to review my code in order to made my code to show chart, because that's what I expected before

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that your course wants you to use `aes_string()` because it's deprecated. Instead you should just use `aes()`, and use `{{` to apply the input parameter.

Regarding the following bit:

```
output$p1 <- renderPlot({
        print(input$continuous_variable) # add print statement to check input value
        print(input$graph_type) # add print statement to check input value
        ggplot(df_country(), aes_string(x = input$continuous_variable, fill = "PREDICTION")) +
            facet_grid(. ~ "PREDICTION") +
            {if(input$graph_type == "Histogram") geom_histogram() else geom_boxplot()}
    })
```

Using `if()` as part of ggplot2 layers isn't going to work. Instead you should build a reactive object for the chart and then use that reactive object in `renderPrint()`, as per below:

```
p1_chart <- reactive({
   p <- ggplot(df_country(), aes(x = {{ input$continuous_variable }}, fill = PREDICTION)) +
    facet_grid(cols = vars(PREDICTION))

  if (input$graph_type == "Histogram") {
   p + geom_histogram()
   } else { 
   p + geom_boxplot()
  }
})

output$p1 <- renderPlot({ p1_chart() })
```

Your code for p2 still has the issue of using `aes_string()` as noted above, so it is best to change it as per the code I provided.